# create several images with one method

Tags: php

hello guys my English is not very good, but i try to explain my self clear.

i got Uploader class and method for creating images with different dimensions.

the problem is that when i'm calling to method couple of times it is always creating one image
with dimensions of last method.
i cant't understand what i'm doing wrong.

thanks for help.

i'm calling to my method like this :

```
$img->uploadMainImage();
$img->createThumbs()->createThumbs(300, 400)->createThumbs(600, 600);
```

here is the method :
upload main image to temp:

```
public function uploadMainImage()
{
    if ($this->_imageError == 0) {

        $this->checkImageSize();
        $this->checkImageExtention();
        $this->checkImageDimensions();

        if(empty($this->_errorCollector)) {
            $this->changeImageName()->moveUploadedImage();
        }

    }

    return $this;
}
```

method for creating thumbs:

```
public function createThumbs($width = null , $height = null, $folder = null)
{
      if (!is_null($width) && !is_null($height)) {
          $this->_thumbsWidth  = $width;
          $this->_thumbsHeight = $height;
      }


      if ($this->_imageHeight > $this->_imageWidth) {

          $this->_thumbsWidth = ($this->_imageWidth / $this->_imageHeight) * $this->_thumbsHeight;
      } else {
          $this->_thumbsHeight = ($this->_imageHeight / $this->_imageWidth) * $this->_thumbsWidth;
      }

      $tmpImg = imagecreatetruecolor($this->_thumbsWidth, $this->_thumbsHeight);

      switch ($this->_imageType) {

          case "image/jpeg":
          case "image/jpg":


              $src = imagecreatefromjpeg($this->_destinationFolder['main'] .  $this->_imageNewName);
              imagecopyresampled($tmpImg, $src, 0, 0, 0 ,0, $this->_thumbsWidth, $this->_thumbsHeight, $this->_imageWidth, $this->_imageHeight);
              imagejpeg($tmpImg, $this->_destinationFolder['thumbs'] .  $this->_imageNewName, 100);
              imagedestroy($src);
              break;
          case "image/png":

              $src = imagecreatefrompng($this->_destinationFolder['main'] .  $this->_imageNewName);
              imagecopyresampled($tmpImg, $src, 0, 0, 0 ,0, $this->_thumbsWidth, $this->_thumbsHeight, $this->_imageWidth, $this->_imageHeight);
              imagepng($tmpImg, $this->_destinationFolder['thumbs'] .  $this->_imageNewName, 24);
              imagedestroy($src);
              break;

      }

    return $this;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$this->_imageNewName` is not unique on each call of `createThumbs`, therefore your just overwriting the same image over and over. Add some logic to your `createThumbs` method to add uniqueness to the name so you will get a new image file each time.

**A sample implementation could be...**

`$this->_myNewThumbName .= sprintf("%s_%dx%d_thumb", $this->_imageNewName, $this->_imageWidth, $this->imageHeight);`

Outputs: `MyCoolSourceImage_400x300_thumb.png`

Comment: if i'm understanding you write  , i must create image name inside each makethumbs function?

Comment: thanks for help. i got it. problem was that is you said :) same image name)